# how to split text using key word and loop it

Tags: c#, split

i have a text and i want to preform the same methods on each line in the text. my problem is that the text is not in line its in one long line(db) example:

```
string text = "dog aa aa aa aa dog bb bb bb bb dog cc cc cc cc dog dd dd dd dd dog"
```

i want to preform my methods each time between the word "dog",

1.preform on aa aa aa aa
2.preform on bb bb bb bb
3.preform on cc cc cc cc
4.preform on dd dd dd dd

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0
for(string[] arr = text.Split("dog"); i < arr.Count; i++)
{
method(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var text = "dog aa aa aa aa dog bb bb bb bb dog cc cc cc cc dog dd dd dd dd dog";
var lines = text.Split(new string[] { "dog" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var line in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

In System.Text.RegularExpressions you can use the static RegEx.Split method to do something like:

```
string[] list = Regex.Split(text, @"dog");
foreach (string s, list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Or you can use the ForEach method:

```
Regex.Split(text, @"dog").ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```